# http response is 500 on code parameter request

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-500

This is a http request to the https://auth.monday.com/oauth2/authorize endpoint on asp.net 6. It should get the code parameter from that endpoint but it's returning a 500 response with html for some reason. This is part of my code grant flow because the API has oauth2.0.

```
public async Task<string> GetCode(string clientId, string redirect_uri)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://auth.monday.com/oauth2/authorize{clientId}");


        string json =
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                new
                {
                    query = "code"
                }
            );
        request.Content = new StringContent(json,
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseText;
    }
```

Comment: Put `try` `catch` and analyse the exception

Comment: 500 means the server is at fault. We can't debug Monday's code. Examine the http response to see if there is any other information that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `/` in your endpoint by any chance? Should it not be `https://auth.monday.com/oauth2/authorize/{clientId}`?

Answer (score -1):

HTTP 500 is an internal server error, this means that the server was unable to handle your request properly. If you have access to the server then I would look there as to why it was unable to handle your request. I don't see anything wrong in your request.